# How can I indicate dependencies to external modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, documentation, jsdoc, ngdoc

I'm starting to document my app using [ngdoc](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation) (a variant of [jsdoc](http://usejsdoc.org/)). The first thing I'm doing is documenting my main module. This module depends on a bunch of angular modules, e.g. [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate). I'd like to indicate these requirements:

```
/** 
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name myApp
 * @requires ngAnimate
 * @requires ngCookies
 ... etc ...
*/
```

However, this generates a link to `http://localhost:9999/#/api/ngAnimate` on *my* server. It assumes, rightly so, that I'm referring to something else in the documentation.

How do I indicate that the requirement is from an external source? e.g. something like:

```
* @requires {@link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate }
```

Answer (score 0):

try that. It's work for me :

```
* @requires https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate
```

Comment: not working, this generates the link: 
`http://localhost:8081/#/https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate`